# validating schema Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: xml, xsd

For my xml file i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<forum>
  <post>
      <description>The Day is coming    </description>
      <date> Thu, 16 Apr 2009 </date>
      <title> cats  </title>
  </post>

  <post>
      <description> its raining </description>
      <date> Tues, 12 Apr 2010 </date>
      <title> dog </title>
  </post>

  <post>
      <description>Game over    </description>
      <date> Tues, 16 Apr 2009 </date>
      <title> frog  </title>
  </post>

  <post>
      <description> Watch </description>
      <date> wednesday, 12 Apr 2010 </date>
      <title> hats </title>
  </post>
</forum>
```

for my xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”>
<xs:element name="forum" type="xs:forumtype">
  <xs:complexType name = "forumtype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="post" type ="posttype"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType> 
   <xs:complexType name="posttype">
       <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

When i try to validate the schema i get Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.  Even though i set the  encoding to "UTF-8" why is it still not liking this?

Answer (score 1):

You should include more information: platform/language, specific error message to make it easier to suggest things.
But assuming error message suggests problem with UTF-8 encoding, this happens at lower level (during XML parsing) and has nothing to do with Schema validation.

Rather, underlying XML document uses different encoding than what parser was told it should -- most commonly content uses something like `Latin-1` (ISO-8859-1) encoding (or similar). You can verify this by just parsing the document, and should get similar error, regardless of schema.

So you may have a broken document (encoding used is not one that XML declaration has); or code you are using claims wrong encoding.

Comment: I am using http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/ ,which compares schema against xml and validates them.  My schema is not "well formed" apparently, implying the error lies in my schema syntax

Comment: Right, you can get parsing error while trying to read schema definition. But error that mentions UTF-8 does suggest a low-level problem, sort of below well-formedness...

Answer (score 0):

I used a free editor and it was defaulting to unicode.  changing the encoding fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You posted the XML *text*, but the error is actually complaining about the *binary* representation stored in the source. The binary source is apparently not really UTF-8.